# Read 1 message concurrently from multiple Kafka topics

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I set the concurrency as 1 for my Kafka Listener.

```
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Map<String, Object>> 
    factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.setConcurrency(conncurrency);
    factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
    factory.setRetryTemplate(retryTemplate());
```

I am listening to 3 different topics

```
    @KafkaListener(topics = "#{'${kafka.consumer.topic.name}'.split(',')}", containerFactory = "kafkaListenerContainerFactory")
    public void listen(@Payload Map<String, Object> conciseMap,
            @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_PARTITION_ID) int partition,
            @Header(KafkaHeaders.OFFSET) int offset,
            Acknowledgment ack) {           
        processMessage(conciseMap,partition,offset,ack,false);
    }
```

In this case , will the listener read one message from the first topic & once it is processed read 1 message from next topic and so on? Or will it concurrently process 1 message from each topic.

If it is former , is there a way to read 1 message concurrently from all the topics without creating multiple listeners?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no guarantee how the Kafka broker will allocate the partitions across the container threads; if you only have one partition; they will probably all be allocated to the same container thread. That's what just happened when I ran a test with container concurrency=3...

> 2017-10-31 16:40:26.066  INFO 35202 --- [ntainer#0-2-C-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : partitions assigned:[]
>
> 2017-10-31 16:40:26.066  INFO 35202 --- [ntainer#0-1-C-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : partitions assigned:[]
>
> 2017-10-31 16:40:26.079  INFO 35202 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : partitions assigned:[bar-0, foo-0, baz-0]

With 10 partitions per topic, I got this distribution...

> 2017-10-31 16:46:19.279  INFO 35900 --- [ntainer#0-1-C-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : partitions assigned:[foo10-5, foo10-6, foo10-4, baz10-5, baz10-4, baz10-6, bar10-5, bar10-4, bar10-6]
>
> 2017-10-31 16:46:19.279  INFO 35900 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : partitions assigned:[bar10-1, bar10-0, bar10-3, bar10-2, baz10-1, baz10-0, baz10-3, baz10-2, foo10-3, foo10-1, foo10-2, foo10-0]
>
> 2017-10-31 16:46:19.279  INFO 35900 --- [ntainer#0-2-C-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : partitions assigned:[baz10-9, baz10-8, baz10-7, bar10-9, bar10-8, foo10-9, bar10-7, foo10-7, foo10-8]

As you can see, some partitions from each topic were allocated to each thread. But two of the threads got 9 partitions total while one got 12.

If you want complete control, I would suggest a listener per topic.

Comment: Thanks Gary! How is the number of container threads determined? If I set concurrency to 1 , will 3 container threads still be created?

Comment: No; `concurrency=3` means 3 threads. It is independent of how many topics you are listening to.

Comment: if i have 1 topic and 1 partition , will only 1 thread be active at a time?

Comment: Correct because a partition can only be allocated to one thread at a time.

Comment: When I assign 3 topics each with 1 partition assigned to a single listener and set concurrency to 3 , will each thread process data from 1 topic (most likely scenario)?

Comment: Please read my answer carefully; there is no guarantee and, when I tested it, all 3 single partitioned topics were given to the same thread; the other two got none.

Comment: Thanks Gary , it is clear now. So the thread that is assigned all the 3 partitions , will it process the assigned messages sequentially?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to create multiple listeners - you only need as big concurrency as much partitions you have throughout all the topics provides or even more.

There will be just spinned such an amount of `KafkaMessageListenerContainer` and each of them will work in its own thread. You still are able to use the same `@KafkaListener` method. As long as you are stateless there, you don't have any problem with the concurrency.

Comment: Thanks @ArtemBilan. Assuming I just have 1 partition , if I set concurrency to 5 , will 5 messages from the single topic be processed concurrently? Or should I use a batch listener for that?

Comment: No, all messages from one partition go to the same consumer thread. That is how Apache Kafka designed.

Comment: If I have 5 partitions & set concurrency to 5 , I guess 5 messages will be processed by 1 consumer thread each. However I if set concurrency to 1 , then the messages will be processed one by one. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: See my answer about how partition assignment works with `concurrency`.